# Autofac Getting the current identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a **Service** and virtually every method requires the current user to execute. Before I started using autofac I basically created a public property like this:

```
private IOrderProvider _orderProvider;

public IOrderProvider OrderProvider => _orderProvider ?? (_orderProvider = new OrderProvider((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity));
```

Because this was a public property on the controller, it would have access to the **User**. Now using autofac I register my **Service** in the **StartupConfig**. Naturally I don't have access to the **User** there.

Is there a way to inject the current user into the **OrderProvider** constructor, or another way to get at it?

Comment: Create a service that wraps the HttpContext and exposes the User principle or identity. which ever one you want

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user principal can be accessed through the `HttpContext.Current.User`. How ever tightly coupling code to HttpContext is frowned upon as it is not very unit test friendly. so create a service that exposes what you want.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
public interface IPrincipalProvider
{
    IPrincipal User { get; }
}
```

An implementation in production can look like this.

```
using System.Security.Principal;    
public class DefaultPrincipalProvider : IPrincipalProvider
{
    public IPrincipal User
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User;
        }
    }
}
```

With that done update the dependent class to use the abstraction

```
public class OrderProvider : IOrderProvider
{
    private readonly ClaimsIdentity identity;
    public OrderProvider(IPrincipalProvider provider) {
        identity = (ClaimsIdentity)provider.User.Identity;
    }
}
```

and then register the provider on startup as usual

```
//...other code removed for brevity

builder.RegisterType<DefaultPrincipalProvider>().As<IPrincipalProvider>();
builder.RegisterType<OrderProvider>().As<IOrderProvider>();

//...other code removed for brevity
```

The service should get everything injected

```
public class Service {
    private readonly IOrderProvider _orderProvider;

    public Service(IOrderProvider orderProvider) {
        _orderProvider = orderProvider;
    }

    public IOrderProvider OrderProvider => _orderProvider;
}
```

Comment: With this "Service", won't that need to be registered too? and then injected into the controller? and I assume I would have to do something like: `private readonly Service _service` and then when I want the order provider do I need to do `_service.OrderProvider` ?

Comment: Yes. I only demonstrated the portion relating to accessing the IPrinciple. I don't have full knowledge of your architecture. It was just a simple example. I assumed you would have had your service already registered.

Comment: im talking about your wrapper service for the orderProvider? Unless you see that as the controller?

Comment: Ok now I'm confused about what you are saying. please clarify. The `Service` in my example was based solely on your mention of `I have a Service and virtually every method requires the current user to execute`

Comment: I only added the User abstraction. everything else came from your original example. I included them in the answer only to show how they fit together.

Comment: The service in my example was the orderProvider :)